# What does (311&255) mean in C++?

Tags: c++, memory

What does the statement  "(311&255)" mean in C++ and how does it relate to speeding up memory access when the second number is a power of two instead of any number?

Comment: A single `&` is a bitwise and. E.g., 311 is `100110111` in binary and 255 is `11111111` in binary. `311 & 255` evaluates to `110111`, or 55.

Comment: It does not relate to speeding up memory access.

Comment: Ah, i see. I think i made an error when i said it speeds up memory access. I meant that it speeds up texture tilling access by saving a division operation.

Comment: I guess it could also speed up memory access by deciding which chunk (power of two width) to load in before letting the cache decide, if your structure fits in.

Comment: Just to clarify before, when I asked "how does it relate to speeding up memory access" I guess I meant how does it speed up the tiling process by avoiding any integer multiplication, by setting all the bits past the power of two value to zero, but I can see why it would now. Thanks for all the useful tips and pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '&' operator is a binary, *bitwise* operator, and can be used to accomplish "bit masking" when used in an expression like `(311 & 255)`.

311 in binary is 100110111.  When you perform an AND operation with 255 (which is 11111111 in binary), the result is to set any bits to the left of bit 7 to zero.  In this case, the result is 00110111 - the most significant bit was set to 0.  This is what is referred to when one set of bits is used to "mask" another set.

```
  100110111
& 011111111
-----------
  000110111
```

This kind of operation is often used when calculating memory addresses because caches and memory buses are typically aligned to power-of-two sizes, which means when you access an address that is a power of two, you fit more of that chunk of memory into the cache and need fewer trips to the memory bus to fetch it.  In order for this to really be an advantage, a software designer (i.e., you) has to plan out memory allocations with awareness of this fact.

It's a really good idea to know exactly what your hardware does if you want to be responsible for memory at this level.